# Divide and Conquer to find maximum difference in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem where given an array I need to calculate the maximum difference such that the larger element appears after the smaller element.

**Here is a better problem statement**:

*Given the stock prices on each day for `n` days, what is the maximum profit a person can make by doing exactly one transaction. One transaction means that the person can buy exactly one stock on one day and sell it on a later date.*

I am trying to solve this problem using divide and conquer algo.

In my recursive function i am trying to spilt the array into two halves, but i am not sure on how to proceed with logic. Do i just get the max difference in each halves and compare?

```
int calculateMaxDiff(int *src, int start, int end){
    if(end - start == 1) return src[start];

    int middle = (start + end)/ 2;
    int half1_diff;
    int half2_diff;
    half1_diff = calculateMaxDiff(src, start, middle);
    half2_diff = calculateMaxDiff(src, middle, end);

    //Do i need to have two loops here that calculate the diffs for each halves
    .... 
    return max(half1_diff, half2_diff);
 }
```

Edit: **Example output**

Give an array {12, 9, 18, 3, 7, 11, 6, 15, 6, 1 ,10} should return 12 as a result of difference between 15 and 3

Comment: What is this even trying to achieve? Do you have sample usage cases and expected results?

Comment: @tadman i added an example output

Comment: So you need to compute the maximum *and* minimum values for your whole array. There's no need for recursion here, just two variables and a single iteration loop. In fact, I don't think you can (efficiently) solve this with recursion.

Comment: yes i know but i am trying to achieve this using divide and conquer

Comment: I know what you're trying, but I think it's not just pointless but impossible with just one return value.

Comment: Divide and Conquer is a method to solve some kind of problems. Don't try to use it for a problem that doesn't obviously requires it. Of course you can Divide to find a local minimum and maximum and Conquer to "globalize" these searches, but it will just be *ad-hoc*.

Comment: @RRP Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question in your problem can be translated into a better problem statement:

*Given the stock prices on each day for n days, what is the maximum profit a person can make by doing exactly one transaction. One transaction means that the person can buy exactly one stock on one day and sell it on a later date.*

**The divide-and-conquer solution**:  Let's see if we can solve this by splitting the input in half, solving the problem in each subarray, then combining the two together. Turns out we actually can do this, and can do so efficiently! The intuition is as follows. If we have a single day, the best option is to buy on that day and then sell it back on the same day for no profit. Otherwise, split the array into two halves. If we think about what the optimal answer might be, it must be in one of three places:

1. The correct buy/sell pair occurs completely within the first half.
2. The correct buy/sell pair occurs completely within the second half.
3. The correct buy/sell pair occurs across both halves - we buy in the first half, then sell in the second half.

We can get the values for (1) and (2) by recursively invoking our algorithm on the first and second halves. For option (3), the way to make the highest profit would be to buy at the lowest point in the first half and sell in the greatest point in the second half. We can find the minimum and maximum values in the two halves by just doing a simple linear scan over the input and finding the two values. This then gives us an algorithm with the following recurrence:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)

T(n) = O(nlogn)
```

Here is a simple implementation in Python. Its very simple to understand and its also easy to convert to C++:

```
def DivideAndConquerSingleSellProfit(arr):
    # Base case: If the array has zero or one elements in it, the maximum
    # profit is 0.
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return 0;

    # Cut the array into two roughly equal pieces.
    left  = arr[ : len(arr) / 2]
    right = arr[len(arr) / 2 : ]

    # Find the values for buying and selling purely in the left or purely in
    # the right.
    leftBest  = DivideAndConquerSingleSellProfit(left)
    rightBest = DivideAndConquerSingleSellProfit(right)

    # Compute the best profit for buying in the left and selling in the right.
    crossBest = max(right) - min(left)

    # Return the best of the three
    return max(leftBest, rightBest, crossBest)
```

**Edit:** Here is the C++ implementation for the above algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int calculateMin(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int i,mini;
    mini = a[low];
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<mini)
        {
            mini = a[i];
        }
    }
    return mini;
}
int calculateMax(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int i,maxi;
    maxi = a[low];
    for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>maxi)
        {
            maxi = a[i];
        }
    }
    return maxi;
}
int calculateMaxDiff(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low>=high)
        return 0;

    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int leftPartition = calculateMaxDiff(a,low,mid);
    int rightPartition = calculateMaxDiff(a,mid+1,high);
    int left = calculateMin(a,low,mid); // calculate the min value in the left partition
    int right = calculateMax(a,mid+1,high); // calculate the max value in the right partition
    return max(max(leftPartition, rightPartition), (right - left));

}
int main() {
    int arr[] = {12, 9, 18, 3, 7, 11, 6, 15, 6, 1 ,10};
    int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int ans = calculateMaxDiff(arr, 0, len-1);
    cout << "Maximum Profit: " <<ans<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: No offense, but I find it a little excessive to call this O(nlgn) algorithm "efficient" when a linear (and at least as simple) version exists ;)

Comment: Thanks @User_Targaryen for the breakdown

Comment: @PatriceGahide: The author was trying to implement the divide and conquer technique to this problem. That is why I provided the divide and conquer approach. Even I know that there is a simple linear solution to the problem!!!!

Comment: I understand perfectly, and this indeed answers the question beautifully. It's just that you say this O(nlgn) algorithm is "efficient", without even mentioning the fact that a simple traversal algorithm is asymptotically better than the solution you present here, or (and even more importantly) that D&C can *also* achieve linear-time complexity with just a few adjustments. Considering that, the word "efficient" seemed a little optimistic, that's all. No big deal.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need in complicated D/C algorithm because simple cycle with checking like

```
 maxdiff = max(current - min_so_far, maxdiff)
 update min_so_far
```

solves the problem

If you really want to apply divide and conquer method, you may return triplet `{local_min, local_max, local_max_diff}` from recursive function like:

```
left = calculateMaxDiff(start, middle)
right = calculateMaxDiff(middle + 1, end)
return {min(left.local_min, right.local_min), 
        max(left.local_max, right.local_max), 
        max(left.local_diff, right.local_diff, right.localmax - left.local_min)
```

Comment: it should be maxdiff = max(current - min_so_far, maxdiff)

Answer (score 1):

The key for a divide and conquer algorithm is the conquer part.

For this problem the most important condition is:

> the larger element appears after the smaller element

For an array `src`, after dividing `src` to 2 halves, `half1` and `half2`, suppose the answer would be in position `i` and `j`, there are 3 cases now:

1. `i` and `j` are both in `half1` -> `half1_diff`
2. `i` and `j` are both in `half2` -> `half2_diff`
3. `i` is in `half1` and `j` is in `half2`

So the main part is to deal with case3. As the larger one comes after, so we just need to find the minimum value `min_half1` in `half1` and the maximum value `max_half2` in `half2`, and check if it meets the condition `max_half2 >= min_half1` and update the result as `max(half1_diff, half2_diff, max_half2-min_half1)`.

In order to calculate `min_half1` and `max_half2` efficiently, you have to keep the record of `min` and `max` value of the array, and it takes `O(1)` time.

So `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)`, `T(n) = O(n)`.

---

Check the example for more details

http://ideone.com/TbIL2r