# Divide and conquer approach to find the minimum difference(absolute value) between two elem in array A[lo..hi]

Tags: algorithm

Input an array A[lo..hi] of n real numbers.

Requirement:

1. Should not use a sorting algorithm.
2. Complexity: `O(nlgn)`

Similar problem: [Divide and Conquer to find maximum difference in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40503101/divide-and-conquer-to-find-maximum-difference-in-an-array)

My solution:

```
int minimum_diff (A[lo..hi])
{
   int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
   int min_diff = Math.abs(A[mid+1] - A[lo]);

   for (int i = lo; i <= mid; i++)
   {
      for (int j = mid + 1; j <= hi; j++)
      {
         if (Math.abs (A[j] - A[i]) < min_diff)
            min_diff = Math.abs (A[j] - A[i]) ;
      }
   }
   int left_min_diff = minimum_diff(A[lo..mid]);
   int right_min_diff = minimum_diff(A[mid+1..hi);
   return max(max(left_min_diff, right_min_diff), min_diff);
}
```

What's wrong with my solution and is the complexity of my solution O(nlgn)?

(I think the complexity of my solution is O(n^2) so it's wrong?)

Comment: Repeatedly partition the array while computing the difference between the pivot and the elements. Handle an array of size 2 as a special case, so that you can claim that you didn't actually sort the array.

Comment: @user3386109 How will that find that e.g. input `0, 10, 20, 30, 25, 11, 15, 5` has a minimum difference of 1 (between 10 and 11)?

Comment: Does "minimum absolute difference" mean the difference of their absolute (i.e. unsigned) values, e.g. minimum absolute difference of `-5` and `7` is **2**? Or is it **12**, regardless of whether you compare `-5` vs `7`, or `7` vs `-5`?

Comment: @Andrease Sorry I didn't make it clear. It should be 7-(-5) = 12, so I mean the smallest difference (in absolute value) of any two elements in array. Yes,  it's 12  regardless of whether you compare -5 vs 7, or 7 vs -5

Comment: @Andreas The elements with the minimum difference (10 and 11 in your example) will never be separated by partitioning. That's because there is no number between them that can be used as a pivot. So there are only two possibilities. Either one of them will be chosen as the pivot, and compared with the other. Or they will end up in a subarray of size two, and their absolute difference will be computed. There is simply no way that they can be put into separate partitions.

Comment: Welcome!
Does `A[lo..hi]` implies that the items in the array are sorted?
Well, it seems that they are indexes.
Please explain (I don't know which programming-language you are using)...
Perhaps you can give some sample data.

Comment: @user3386109 So you're basically applying a [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), even though the requirement is that it "should not use a sorting algorithm"?

Comment: @Andreas Your answer also sorts the array, and it's not divide and conquer. Instead of using `lower()` and `higher()`, you could simply perform an in-order traversal after building the tree. With my method, the array technically never reaches the final sorted order. That's the reason for treating subarrays of size 2 as a base case. If the subarray is {11, 10}, and you compute the difference without swapping the elements, then the final array is not in sorted order. And yes, it's all just semantics, because the only O(nlogn) solution to the problem involves sorting, you just can't call it that.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, ok, I concede the point you're making. Both solutions uses sorting algorithms, without actually iterating a sorting result.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's a good way to put it. Cheers.

Comment: What is the complexity of (n-1)(n-2)/2?
If it's not O(n^2), then:
`/* JavaScript */
function minDiff(array) {
  var md = Infinity;
  var k = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1 && md; i++)
    for(var j = i + 1; j < array.length && md; j++)
      md = Math.min(md, Math.abs(array[i] - array[j]));
  return md;
}`

Comment: @iAmOren _O( (n-1)(n-2)/2 )_ = _O( n*n/2 - 1.5n + 1 )_ = _O(n^2)_

Comment: @Andreas, thank you.
That's what I was afraid of...

Comment: @iAmOren The array is unsorted.

Comment: Please define "a sorting algorithm" for the purposes here.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE** Oops! I was thinking the question was tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java). Java's `TreeSet` is a built-in [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (a [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) to be precise), so any similar data structure in other languages can be used.*

In Java, use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), and the [`lower(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#lower-E-) and [`higher(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher-E-) methods to find the nearest value previously seen.

Since the 3 methods (`add()`, `lower()`, and `higher()`) called for each input value are all *O(log n)*, the result is *O(n log n)*.

With a artificial restriction like *"should not use a sorting algorithm"*, the question is a test or challenge, so I'll leave the actual coding to you.

Comment: @trincot The "Requirement" list in the question didn't say it must be "divide and conquer", so that is just OP making it a *potential* [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454) by choosing a divide and conquer approach.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a potential XY problem. I don't see how divide and conquer could help to solve this problem. Maybe I should ignore the subject of the question.

Comment: @trincot See comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398986/divide-and-conquer-approach-to-find-the-minimum-differenceabsolute-value-betwe/64399242?noredirect=1#comment113875476_64398986

Comment: I would need to see that idea in more detail. Looks like Quick Sort, leaving out a swap at the deepest recursion level.